# Laravel delete previous session

Tags: ajax, laravel, session

i have two post call method with jQuery .

```
$.post('/search/session1',post);
$.post('/search/session2',post);
```

each call make session data .

```
public function session1(Request $request){
Session::put('session1','1');
}
public function session2(Request $request){
Session::put('session2','2');
}
```

first create session1 . but when call post2, session2 create and session1 remove!!! This is very strange. i used laravel 5.4 .

**Update:**

I create two session before call Ajax , and not removed on post2 call ! every time only session1 removed !!!

**Update 2**

i saved session in 3 bellow laravel method and still session1 removed !

```
Session::put('session1','1')
session('session1',1)
$request->session()->put('session1','1')
```

Comment: With your edit, my answer is not applicable anymore. It would not help. So I deleted it, ok?  :)

Comment: Its because you are sending two separate requests and there is a *race condition*. Avoid sessions manipulation via AJAX calls.

Comment: thanks . but how? it means i cant use ajax call for session?

Comment: Its limitation of all drivers (database, redis); read any of these https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue+session+race+is%3Aclosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Kyslik this package solve my problem :

- https://github.com/rairlie/laravel-locking-session